# How do I implement java tic tac toe game features

Tags: java, javafx

I'm having trouble with this assignment for school. I would like to implement a method, where the code says `//call method to check for winner`, to check for a winner after each turn. 
I am unsure how to do this. I have tried various different ways. Then I would like the name of the winner "X wins" or "O wins" to be displayed on the tic tac toe board.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.geometry.*;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static int turn = 1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    } //end main

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Play Tic Tac Toe!");

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 275);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                grid.add(createButton(), i, j);
            }
        }
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static Button createButton() {
        //instantiates button objects with the same properties
        Button b = new Button(" ");
        b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                //implemennt Tic Tac Toe logic
                if(turn % 2 != 0) {
                    b.setText("X");
                }
                else  {
                    b.setText("O");
                }

                int row = GridPane.getRowIndex(b);
                int col = GridPane.getColumnIndex(b);
                //outputs to the terminal
                System.out.println("Turn = " + turn + " Row = " + row + " Col = " + col);
                b.setDisable(true); //after button is clicked, disable it
                // call method to check for winner
                turn++;
            }
        });
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: A quote from the Web page [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ___Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer___ Did you not try searching the Internet for the terms ___javafx tic tac toe___ ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could do this. For the sake of keeping this as your own work I will not be posting code for you and only referencing potential solutions and algorithms you could use.

The first thing you need to do is create a way to store the `state` of the board. Since the board is small`(3x3)`, I would just use a simple `integer array`. There are three possible `states`, I would say that Empty is `0`, X is `1`, and O is `2`. I would assign `0-2` to be the top `3`, `3-5` to be the middle, and `6-8` the bottom. To make things simpler I might write a `get` and `set` function for this `array` so that I can,

For example, write `set(X,Y,State)` to set that square to that state or get to retrieve that state. Once I have this system set up I would need to devise a way for myself to find out whether or not someone has one. For this I would write a loop to check each square. If the square is empty then do nothing, but if it has an `x` or an `o`, store the coordinates as say `x1,y1` then check all of the adjacent squares. If any of the adjacent squares have the same state, then store the coordinates as `x2,y2` otherwise just move to the next square.

Finally, check to see if either of the following coordinate pairs exist on the board:`(2*x2-x1,2*y2-y1)` and `(2*x1-x2,2*y1-y2)`. If they do, then check to see if the state of that square is the same as the first two. If it is then whatever the state is of that square corresponds to the player that won.